# How can I create a vector with unique values from a specific column?

Tags: r, datatable, unique

I have a data table and I would like to create a vector that cointains all the unique values from that column. After that, I would like to download it and use it in excel.

The column from which I want to derive the vector is "Estacao":

[image]

Comment: Assuming your data table is named `dt` and the variable of interest is `var1`, you can do `write.csv(unique(dt$var1), file="path/to/file.csv")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.